# How to check weblogs in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, server, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

My application is deployed on IIS 7. I want to check the number of failures as my logic is getting failed at some point and getting errors.Is there any general weblogs in IIS.I can only see system errors in the event logs. Is there any web logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is a folder named 'logs' in your 'inetpub' folder where all the logs live.  You can look at the Logging tab under IIS in IIS Manager to see the name of the specific log you should check for your site.

Comment: i can see my site but where can i find the specific log of my site

Comment: You need to look in IIS Manager for your site to find the specific location of the log you need.

Comment: i have only two sites in my server running. Default Site and MySite. I can see text files under inetpub folder but where can i see the query strings used to make a request. My FailedReqLogFiles is empty

Comment: Try looking in the W3SVC(x) where (x) is the location for your specific site.

Answer (score 1):

Manually trawling the standard W3C logs is ok if you're chasing down requests for certain content types, but they won't tell you an awful lot about why your web application is failing and responding with many `4XX` and `5XX` status codes. You'll get a status code, but that's about it.

**Failed Request Tracing:**

Your ***"go to"*** diagnostic tool should be the Failed Request Tracing feature that is built into IIS7+.

FRT is one of my favourite features of IIS7/8 for tracking down problems with production sites, especially when debugging apps built on the WebAPI and Ajaxy type stuff.

For more information see:

> http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing

For example, last week FRT helped me get to the bottom of an issue with a client's hosted site. A particular part of the site (which uses the WebAPI) was failing with a `405 Method Not Allowed` status code when making a HTTP `DELETE` request and despite the `DELETE` verb being permitted.

Using FRT I was able to generate trace of the failing request which showed me this:

[image]

Expanding the "View Trace" entries revealed this error:

[image]

The solution for our customer was to disable (it's not used) the WebDAV native module which doesn't permit non-Windows authenticated requests with certain verbs (such as `DELETE`) to complete. Even if the WebDAV module isn't handling the request it's still in the request pipeline inspecting and validating request headers.

Failed Request Tracing is a really invaluable diagnostic tool, you should learn how to use it.

**The HTTPERR Logs:**

You should also check the HTTPERR logs located in:

```
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR
```

If you get `503 - Service Unavailable` errors they're a good place to look for clues as to what went wrong if an application pool fails catastrophically, and often.